# Orientation change notification in Android

Tags: android, orientation, onconfigurationchanged

Trying to follow something. Boiling down to simplest: In my AndroidManifest.xml I have the following:

```
<application
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:configChanges="orientation"
 ...
</application>
```

In my activity that runs I have this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.d("PrimesAreInP", "onConfigurationChanged called");
}
```

However when I change the orientation of the phone from portrait to landscape I never see the onConfigurationChanged() print. What else do I need to do to see this call?

Comment: Add this to the activity properties in the manifest

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this for activity tag:

`<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboa‌​rdHidden"`

Comment: Has that orientation happened??

Comment: What is your Api level??

Comment: In my android manifest I also have this:
    <uses-sdk>
      android:minSdkVersion="16"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    </uses-sdk>

Comment: Try adding this for activity tag,:    <activity
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66716/discussion-between-zubair-and-user3079275).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this dude :

```
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

and not forget to write this line in activity tag of your menifest :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

good luck !!!